# Users cannot type into my html text boxes

Tags: html

As a year end prank one of the directors at the firm I work for wanted a fake bonuses application form. He found something he though was a great idea, but we squashed it as it was an executable. I slapped together an HTML page to do what he wanted, but I've got an issue -- none of the text areas are writeable. Here's the code (with some alterations for privacy):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<head><title>[Company Name] Annual Bonus Application</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function moveObj(obj){
var w = 600, h = 400;
newWidth = Math.floor(Math.random()*w);
newHeight = Math.floor(Math.random()*h);
obj.style.position="absolute";
obj.style.left=newWidth+"px";
obj.style.top=newHeight+"px";
}
function checkObj(event,obj){
var top = obj.style.top.split("px")[0];
var left = obj.style.left.split("px")[0];
if(top+5 > event.y || left+5 > event.x){moveObj(obj);}
}
window.setTimeout("checkObj(event,document.forms[0].elements[0]", 1);
document.onkeydown = function(){return false;}
//--></script>

</head>


<body>
<p>
<img src = "Company_logo_rgb_highres.jpg" alt = "[Company] Logo">
<h1>[Company Name] Annual Review Bonus Submission Form </h1></p><BR>
<form>
Name: <input type="text" size="25" name ="name" value=""> 
Supervising Director: <input type="text" size="25" name="Supervisor" value="">
Hours Billed: <input type="text" size="5" name="HRs_billed" value=""><br><br>

Your Top Three achievements this year:<BR><textarea name="Achievements" cols="75" rows="5"></textarea><BR>
Your Top Three areas of improvement this year:<br> <textarea name="Improvements" cols="75" rows="5"></textarea><BR>
Your Top Three mistakes this year, and resoltution plan:<br><textarea name="Blunders" cols="75" rows="10"></textarea><BR> 
<p>
In a hundred words or less, why should we give YOU a bonus?: <br> <textarea name="Name" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
</form>

<onMouseMove="checkObj(event,document.forms[0].elements[0]);" onKeyPress="return    false;">
<form action="" name="frm"><div>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onMouseOver="moveObj(this);">
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onClick=window.close();>
</div></form>
</body>

<footer>
<table border =0>
<TR bgcolor="#6D8877">  
   <TD>Redacted <br>
       Redacted.</TD>

 </footer>

 </html>
```

Essentially its the tired old gag where every time you try to click on the submit button the button moves... But for the sake of realism I want them to fill out the form before hitting submit...

If anyone can see (and point out) my mistake that would great...

Comment: <onMouseMove> is not a valid HTML tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
document.onkeydown = function(){return false;}
```

It (i assume) unintentionally gets executed, because your HTML comment here:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
//--></script>
```

doesn't affect the actual contents of the script tag.

If you want to use a HTML comment to avoid the execution of your script, you can use:

```
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
</script>//-->
```

I would use javascript commentary instead (probably out of personal preference):

```
/* to start a comment
*/ to end one
```

and

```
// to comment out a single line
```

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*
         alert('this will not appear, because it is commented code'); 
    */
</script>
```

**Hints**

As *Diodeo* mentioned, `<onMouseMove>` is not a valid tag and will not have any effect (unless your document is somehow additionally parsed, preprocessed or you are using some additional JS library that actually deals with such tags explicitely).

Comment: Sorry the comment was unintentional -- left over from testing the function... The whole idea behind the page is that the script execute -- it moves the submit button whenever the mouse hovers over it. You are correct in that correctly commenting out the script allows the text boxes to be written to... Perhaps the script is misplaced in the code? or perhaps that line should be commented out... Thanks, I'll test.

Comment: No problem, but the point is that your comment was there but had no effect, therefore `document.onkeydown = function(){return false;}` was effective and thus any inputs on your page couldn't work because the `onkeydown` handler was intercepting any input from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line: document.onkeydown = function(){return false;}

Just remove the line - the button doesn't submit the form anyway, since you used type="button"